# Reversing strings in C - Memory Direction

Tags: c, pointers

Recently I've been learning about Strings and Pointers in C and have learned that you can do some pretty cool things in C using pointer arithmetic which reversing a String is one of these things. The following is the code that I am working with:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void print_reverse_string(char s[])
{
    size_t length = strlen(s);

    char *beginning = s;
    char *end = beginning + length - 1;    

    while(end >= beginning)
    {
        printf("%c", *end);
        end = end - 1;
    }    
}

int main() 
{
    printf("Please enter string to reverse: ");
    char input_string[20];
    fgets(input_string, 20, stdin);

    /* Get rid of new line character from fgets function */
    input_string[strlen(input_string) - 1] = '\0';

    printf("Reversed string: ");
    print_reverse_string(input_string);

    return 0;
}
```

My concern begins with the following line of code:

`char *end = beginning + length - 1;`

This assumes that the ending memory location of an array will always be greater than the beginning memory location. Is this something that I should be concerned about as a C programmer or can I always be guaranteed that

`&randomArray[0] < &randomArray[1] < &randomArray[2] < .... < &randomArray[lastElement]`

It's just that I have been reading about different memory spaces and how certain spaces grow upwards while others grow downwards, for example, the stack growing downwards and the heap growing upwards, and thought that there might be a possibility of arrays growing downward in size.

Could this occur on a certain architecture or am I overthinking this possibility?

Comment: C11 draft standard, `6.5.8 Relational operators 5 [...]If the objects pointed to are members of the same aggregate object, pointers to structure members declared later compare greater than pointers to members declared earlier in the structure, and pointers to array elements with larger subscript values compare greater than pointers to elements of the same array with lower subscript values. [...]`.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. This makes sense, it would be crazy to have to check the direction of growth of arrays each time pointer arithmetic was involved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`char *end = beginning + length - 1;` leads to undefined behavior when `length == 0`.  Example: "ending memory location of an array will always be greater" may be true expect code wants it to be false.  Pointer arithmetic such as `beginning + length - 1` is only valid from the beginning of an object to 1 object past its end.  So `beginning + 0 - 1` is UB.

Subsequent (like in an array) objects' **addresses compare in increasing order** - regardless of their underlying values, but the arithmetic is valid only in a narrow range.

Better to do

```
char *end = beginning + length;
while(end > beginning) {  
  end = end - 1; 
  printf("%c", *end);
}
```

---

Side issue: Should the first character read via `fgets()` is `'\0'`, the below code attempts `input_string[SIZE_MAX] = '\0'`

```
 // do not use
input_string[strlen(input_string) - 1] = '\0';
// alternatives
if (*input_string) input_string[strlen(input_string) - 1] = '\0';
// or
input_string[strcspn(input_string, "\n")] = '\0';
```

Answer (score 3):

C arrays are always allocated contiguously in memory, from lowest address to highest.

Answer (score 1):

> This assumes that the ending memory location of an array will always be greater than the beginning memory location.

Yes, your assumption is correct. An array stores its elements in contiguous memory locations and in increasing order.

Answer (score 0):

All answers above me were correct. When you write

```
char input_string[20];
```

you get `20*sizeof(char)` bytes allocated on the stack, and `input_string` is only a pointer pointing to the first item, and it is handled like a pointer. For example `input_string[10]` means `*(input_string + 10)`, etc.

Instead of repeating others, here's a tricky solution of the same task. Recursion in C is lovely for me, or black magic for the ignorants :) Takes some time to understand it, though. Not for serious use, but for fun!

The two backsides of recursion are: danger of stack overflow, and inefficiency. Neither of them are relevant to your question.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void reverse()
{
    int c = getchar();
    if (c != '\n' && c != EOF)
    {
        reverse();
        putchar(c);
    }
    else
        printf("Reversed string: ");
}


int main(void)
{
    printf("Please enter string to reverse: ");
    reverse();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Disagree: If "`input_string` is only a pointer pointing to the first item, and it is handled like a pointer", then should not `sizeof input_string` return a value like 4 or 8 rather than 20?  It returns 20.  An array is not a pointer.  Another difference: functions may return a pointer, but not an array.

Comment: Note that `reverse()` will enter infinite recursion should `getchar()` return `EOF`.

Comment: Correct. Don't forget if you pass input_string to a function that has a parameter `char s[]`, then `sizeof(s)` will return 4 or 8. You can pass it to `char s[20]` as well, then it is still an array, not ptr. Also fixed bug in `reverse()`, thx.

Comment: Suggest using `int c` rather than `char c` for complete correct functionality. `getchar()` typically returns 1 of 257 different values.  Code cannot uniquely store that in an 8-bit `char`.